# Realm crashes on create object (React Native)

Tags: android, react-native, realm

This is my RealmService file:

```
import Realm from 'realm';

const AuthSchema = {
    name: 'Auth',
    primaryKey: 'id',
    properties: {
        id: {
            type: 'int',
            indexed: true
        },
        time: 'date',
        username: 'string',
        action: 'string'
    }
}

const WiretransferSchema = {
    name: 'Wiretransfer',
    primaryKey: 'id',
    properties: {
        id: {
            type: 'int',
            indexed: true
        },
        time: 'date',
        source: 'string',
        target: 'string',
        amount: 'float',
        comments: {
            type: 'string',
            optional: true
        }
    }
}

let RealmService = {
    findAllAuth: function() {
        return repository.objects('Auth');
    },

    SaveAuth: function(username, action) {
        Realm.open({
            path: 'testtt.realm',
            schema: [AuthSchema, WiretransferSchema]
        }).then(realm => {

            // Get max ID
            var maxId = realm.objects('Auth').max('id');

            realm.write(() => {
                realm.create('Auth', {
                    id: maxId + 1,
                    time: Date.now(),
                    username: username,
                    action: action
                }, true);
            });

            realm.close();  
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
}

module.exports = RealmService;
```

The app crashes without any errors when this code is called:

```
realm.write(() => {
                realm.create('Auth', {
                    id: maxId + 1,
                    time: Date.now(),
                    username: username,
                    action: action
                }, true);
            });
```

Just the write method doesn't crash the app. It's the create method.

If I disable the debugging tools in React Native the app doesn't crash but there is nothing in the realm file added.

I've tried RN 0.57.1 and 0.57.8. Reinstalled realm and still no luck. What could the problem be?

Comment: make sure datatypes and objects you are passing are same. I got same crash when my datatype was int and I gave it string.

Comment: new Date() instead of Date.now() fixed it. Why am I not getting errors though? It just crashes the app without any useful information.

Comment: I am glad, I helped you. Posting the answer below so that if any other faces this problem could find answer easily. Request you to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure datatypes and objects you are passing are same. I got same crash when my datatype was **int** and I gave it **string**.

In your case passing `new Date()` will work.

It won't give any errors but app will crash on both android and iOS. Maybe realm team will solve it in future release as this bug already exists in Github forum.